# Global pinia store accessible in every component

Tags: vue.js, pinia

I want to have my pinia "mainStore" to be accessible in whole app using `this.store`

i dont want to import in every component like this

```
import {store} from "@/stores/mainStore";
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Have a look at this https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/discussions/1197

Comment: There's no `this` in Composition API. What do you mean by *"in whole app"*? If you only mean *"Options API whole app"*, then: `app.config.globalProperties.store = store`

Comment: @tao probably what OP meant here indeed, otherwise he would maybe have specified more CAPI-y tags.